# I don't understand why np.argwhere doesn't return something for my first row

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have an array, and I want to find where are the max value for each row.
On the same row I can have the two values that are the maximum, so I decided to use np.argwhere.

```py
np.argwhere(a == np.amax(a,axis=1))
```

but for my first row, it output nothing and I don't understand why.

Comment: a is a Numpy Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.amax` returns a row array, while you want a column one. Hence, you want to reshape your array before performing the computation:

```python
np.argwhere(a == np.amax(a, axis=1).reshape((-1,1)))
```